# What are the models for measuring the time length for impact on a time series?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

Is there any methods or models that I can look into for measuring the impact duration of a shock. In my case, I want to evaluate how long will a policy adjustment(raise the interest rate by 1%) will have its effect(on bond yields) until it reaches a new equilibrium.

Comment: Survival analysis might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis